# Telerik Kendo UI grid incorrectly serializes toolbar button when persisting _if_ rendering with ASP MVC helper

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

Please note: Everything is working perfectly as expected *before* persisting and restoring the state of the grid. So please do not search for error there...

Using ASP MVC helper to render the grid:

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add new role"))
```

When persisting the grid client side using the standard statements:

```
    grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    data = kendo.stringify(grid.getOptions());
```

the data will be partly invalid, especially the toolbar part: (part of JSON text in data variable)

```
   ..."toolbar":{"command":[{"name":null,"buttonType":"ImageAndText","text":"Add new role"}]}...
```

Note the null value of the "name" property. The value should be "create".
As a consequence restoring the data will destroy the toolbar.

I've spent a lot of time to reproduce this in a public javascript version but 
this issue can not be reproduced with the pure Html/Javascript version, because it using the default toolbar definition like this:

```
 ...,
 toolbar: ["create"],
 ...
```

it will be serialized in the data as:

```
 "toolbar":["create"]
```

which is way different we saw in ASP MVC case, and it is correct.
Also if we are setting explicitly the name of the command in Html/javascript like:

```
  ...,
  toolbar: [{name: "create", text: "Add new Customer"}],
  ...
```

it will be serialized as:

```
 "toolbar":[{"name":"create","text":"Add new Customer",
```

which is correct, and differs from what we've seen in ASP MVC version.

Obvious workaround would be to set the command name in ASP MVC explicitly but unfortunatelly the ASP MVC helper do not exposes this property...

Any idea what to patch or how to workaround?

Comment: Have you looked into creating the toolbar as a template?

Comment: if using template he will get JSON like that `toolbar: [],`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK HtmlAttributes make it possible,
but when u are using `grid.getOptions`, the json result won't be like what you expected. Because `getOptions` will return grid definition instead of how your grid rendered.

try this

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create()
                           .Text("Add new role")
                           .HtmlAttributes(new {name = "create" }))
```

the JSON string will be like this

```
 ..."toolbar":{"command":[{"name":null, "attr" : "\"name\" = \"create\"", "buttonType":"ImageAndText","text":"Add new role"}]}...
```

you could modify it a little bit with string `replace` to make it like what you expected

Comment: Dion, I think my diagnosis was a bit optimistic (and also misleading). I've already tried to patch the JSON string before restoring (replace the null) but unfortunately that was not helped...